# Generating word file in the same directory of excel using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I was trying to open a word file using excel macro & copy & paste some data from excel to the opened word file. Then to **save as** the word file in the **same directory** of excel file. But facing errors. Please help.
Here is my code.

```
enter code here

Sub OICD()


 Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\OICD TEMPLATES\OICD_"
    Dim strFileName As String

    strFileName = InputBox("Please enter file name", "Create new file")
    If strFileName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
Dim Word As Object: Set Word = CreateObject("word.application")
Dim docWD As Word.Document
Word.Visible = True

 Set docWD = Word.Documents.Open("C:\Users\owner\Desktop\OICD TEMPLATES\OICD Template V1.docx")


docWD.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFileName), FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT").Range("C7:J56").Copy
Word.Selection.Paste


End Sub
```

Comment: `facing errors`? What kind of errors? Where? You need to be more specific in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code fails because of various reasons. You should learn to debug to easily locate the problems (execute from the code, press f8 until it crashes on certain line for certain reason).

This version does what you want:

```
Sub OICD()

    Const strPath As String = "C:\Users\owner\Desktop\OICD TEMPLATES\OICD_\" 'The last characters has to be a "\"
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim extension As String

    strFileName = InputBox("Please enter file name", "Create new file")
    If strFileName = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

    extension = ".docx" '".doc"

    Dim Word As Object: Set Word = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    Word.Visible = True

    Set docWD = Word.Documents.Open(strPath & strFileName & extension)


    docWD.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strFileName, FileFormat:=wdFormatDocument
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("REPORT").Range("C7:J56").Copy
    Word.Selection.Paste


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
          Option Explicit
          Sub Wordcreation()
       Dim WdObj As Object, fname As String
      fname = "Word"
     Set WdObj = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WdObj.Visible = False
     Range("A1:E8").Select
   Selection.Copy 'Your Copy Range
   WdObj.Documents.Add
  WdObj.Selection.PasteSpecial
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
    If fname <> "" Then 'make sure fname is not blank
      With WdObj
      .ChangeFileOpenDirectory "D:\chandra" 'save Dir
       .ActiveDocument.SaveAs Filename:=fname & "Chandra.doc"
        End With
       Else:
       MsgBox ("File not saved, naming range was botched, guess again.")
        End If
      With WdObj
        .ActiveDocument.Close
        .Quit
       End With
     Set WdObj = Nothing
     End Sub
```